# How to solve ruby string

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby, and I'm trying to make a simple calculator in which a user types in a simple problem (such as addition or subtraction) and the answer is returned. The problem is when the user types in a question, the question itself is being returned instead of the answer to that question.

```
puts "How many Questions?"
questions = gets.chomp.to_i

questions.times do |problem|
    puts "question: "
    problem = gets.chomp
    puts "answer: #{problem}"
end
```

Comment: There is no calculation for the answer.

Comment: Poor form but simple solution as long as you can trust the people entering is `"answer: #{eval(problem)}"` but do not do this. Also no need to pipe in `|problem|` as this would be `n` in times but you are just ignoring it anyway.

Comment: Why should I not use eval if it works? @engineersmnky

Comment: because `eval` will evaluate anything the user puts in there without prejudice this means a knowledgeable user can do a lot of damage and falls under the rule of **NEVER TRUST USER INPUT**. for a non damaging example type the question raise StandardError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop, instead of:

```
problem = gets.chomp
puts "answer: #{problem}"
```

Try this:

```
problem = gets.chomp
solved_problem = eval(problem)
puts "answer : #{solved_problem}"
```

`eval` will take care of interpreting your string as a Ruby instruction. But it's very messy, because anyone could write any Ruby program in your input  and `eval` will make it run, so it's not safe at all.

If you only want to take care of simple operations, you can use a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) first to check if the input string looks like what you want:

```
problem_is_ok = (problem =~ /^\d+ *[+-] *\d+$/)
```

This will be `true` if the string starts with a number, followed by 0 to many spaces, followed by either a `+` or `-` sign, followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by another number and nothing else. Then you raise an error if this is not true.

Your loop now look like this:

```
questions.times do |problem|
    puts "question: "
    problem = gets.chomp
    problem_is_ok = (problem =~ /^\d+ *[+-] *\d+$/)
    if problem_is_ok
        puts "answer: #{eval(problem)}"
    else
        #I raise an error, but you might aswell just print it instead for your simple program
        raise ArgumentError("Can't compute this")
    end
end
```

Comment: Watch out - ^$ are end of line markers, so your code would accept as a valid problem strings such as `"1+2\nputs('hello')"`

Comment: You're right. But in his case, the `problem` string comes from a user input, where he cannot type return without ending the input string.

Comment: Thanks your code worked but could you explain the problem_is_ok line to me? I've never seen the =~ operator before and I would also like to include parentheses in that statement because parentheses cause an error. @Caillou

Comment: `=~` is Ruby's basic pattern-matching operator. When it is used between a regular expression and a string, then the regular expression is used as a pattern to match against the string. Here is the very well explained ruby documentation about Regexp and this operator : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Add and subtract can be simple ruby definitions

We pass in 5 and 1

The lower portion of the code is the clear user interface implementation

when we loop we do it 3 times

It outputs 3 options for the user to select from

We read in with chomp, standard in, the keyboard, chooses 1, 2, or 3

If elsif statements conditionally select for each case

Using string interpolation we render the variables a and b into a new string,
and run their respective methods (add or subtract)

Converting that methods integer output to a string, and concatenate it.

Outputting that to the users screen

The 3rd option does no calculation,

instead it prints to users screen a simple string

our else condition catches the case when people don't enter one of the choices of 1, 2 or 3

It tells you to correct your choice to the options provided

Hope this helps

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
questions = 3
a, b = 5, 1

def add(a,b)
  a + b
end

def subtract(a,b)
  a - b
end

questions.times do |questions|
    puts "Please choose:
      1. add
      2. subtract 
      3. exit"
    questions = gets.chomp

    if questions == '1'
      puts "#{a} + #{b} = " + add(a,b).to_s
    elsif questions == '2'
      puts "#{a} - #{b} = " + subtract(a,b).to_s
    elsif questions == '3'
      puts 'exiting, goodbye.'
      exit
    else
      p 'please choose again'
    end
end
```

Comment: When answering please provide some explaination of the code. Instead of handing someone the answer, teach them why it is the answer so they can build upon it.